# How to Check If a Number Already Exists Before Inserting Data into Google Sheets using PHP and SheetDB

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a PHP script that collects form data and inserts it into a Google Sheet using SheetDB. Before inserting the data, I want to check if the provided phone number (`$_POST['number']`) already exists in the Google Sheet to prevent duplicate entries. Additionally, I would like to know how to handle the SheetDB API response to determine if the data insertion was successful or not.

Here's a simplified version of my current script:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // SheetDB API key
    $api_key = '...';

    // SheetDB API endpoint
    $api_endpoint = '...';

    // Prepare data for SheetDB
    $studyField = $_POST['study-field'];
    $data = [
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'number' => $_POST['number'],
        'phone' => $_POST['phone'],
        'softwares' => $_POST['softwares'],
        'usthb_student' => $_POST['usthb_student'],
        'university_name' => isset($_POST['university_name']) ? $_POST['university_name'] : '',
        'study_field' => $studyField === 'other' ? $_POST['other-f'] : $studyField,
        'message' => $_POST['message'],
    ];

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $api_key,
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($api_endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(['data' => $data]));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Before inserting the data, I want to check if the provided phone number ($_POST['number']) already exists in the Google Sheet to prevent duplicate entries`

Just make a GET request to get all the entries from SheetDB like this:

```
$ch = curl_init($api_endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$fullDat = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Then simple decode the entries and check for the phone number like this:

```
$fullDat = json_decode($fullDat, true);

foreach ($fullDat as $row) {
    if ($row['phone'] == $data['phone']) {
        die('Phone number already inserted before.');
    }
}
```

And if the phone number doesn't exist, you can go forward with setting up the headers and making the POST request.

`I would like to know how to handle the SheetDB API response to determine if the data insertion was successful or not`

When making POST requests, SheetDB provides a field called `created` in the response which is a boolean indicating if the request was  successful or not. Just check that to know if the insertion was successful or not like this:

```
$resp = json_decode($response, true);

if ($resp['created'] == true) {
    echo 'Data inserted successfully.';
} else {
    echo 'Data insertion failed.';
}
```

The full code would look like this:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // SheetDB API key
    $api_key = '...';

    // SheetDB API endpoint
    $api_endpoint = '...';

    // Prepare data for SheetDB
    $studyField = $_POST['study-field'];
    $data = [
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'number' => $_POST['number'],
        'phone' => $_POST['phone'],
        'softwares' => $_POST['softwares'],
        'usthb_student' => $_POST['usthb_student'],
        'university_name' => isset($_POST['university_name']) ? $_POST['university_name'] : '',
        'study_field' => $studyField === 'other' ? $_POST['other-f'] : $studyField,
        'message' => $_POST['message'],
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($api_endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $fullDat = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $fullDat = json_decode($fullDat, true);

    foreach ($fullDat as $row) {
        if ($row['phone'] == $data['phone']) {
            die('Phone number already inserted before.');
        }
    }

    // If phone number hasn't been inserted, proceed with the POST request
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $api_key,
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($api_endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(['data' => $data]));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $resp = json_decode($response, true);

    // Check if data insertion was successful
    if ($resp['created'] == true) {
        echo 'Data inserted successfully.';
    } else {
        echo 'Data insertion failed.';
    }
}
```